# Matlab calculate geographical distance to lat/lng polyline

Tags: matlab, matrix, geospatial

In Matlab I would like to calculate the (shortest) distances between a set of independent points (m-by-2 matrix of lat/lng) and a set of polylines (n-by-2 matrix of lat/lng). The resulting table should be an n-m matrix with distances in KM.

I have rewritten this JavaScript implementation (http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/BdccGeo.js) to Matlab, but it does not seem to perform well.

Currently I am working on a project with a relatively large set of data and running into performance issues. I have roughly 40.000 points and 150 polylines. The polylines are subsets of the original set of 40.000 points. With about 15 seconds per polyline, calculating all these distances can take up to an hour. Also, the intermediate matrixes of 40000x150x3 cause out of memory errors on my lesser machines.

Instead of optimizing or revising this implementation I am wondering if Matlab doesn't already have some (smarter) functions built in for this. But as far as I can see, the documentation mainly has information on how to display geodata as opposed to doing calculations on it.

Does anyone know or have experience with these kind of calculations in Matlab? Has anything like this already been written which I can reuse so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. And finally, is this expected performance, given these numbers, or should my function be able to perform much better?

Comment: 15 seconds per calculation for basic trigonometry is a bit strange. However, without knowing how your rewrite is written there isn't a real good way to answer the question. I would recommend utilizing [MATLAB's profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) to get an idea of where the slowdowns are and provide the relevant code for assistance.

Comment: If your code is unvectorized, function-call heavy, and doesn't perform memory allocation, then it's very possible to see terrible performance. We can't help without seeing an actual example of your code with a small subset of data to test it with. Also, if you have the Matlab [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping/), you might looking to the [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/functionlist.html) it provides.

Comment: I am normally used to process 0.5GB on MAT files, these are about 1M points per MAT, more or less.... Yes, memory errors are ussual under that....

Comment: My suggest would be, if you still want to have MATLAB instead of pure Java, is to have pure simple vectors (try not to use those 40000x150x3 matrices). Calculating those distances should NOT be so heavy!!!...

Comment: @hypfco, [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptnotjava.com/).

Comment: I am totally clear on that :)

Comment: @hypfco, but then you suggestion doesn't make sense. Matlab has no facilities to interface with JavaScript afaik.

Comment: I deleted that,... that could be misinterpreted as you said.....